# Why does list in program give an unexpected output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem with my list in python.

I am printing out the list (working), a number that shows the line number (working) and an item in the list that should change every time the list is printed(not working?)

```
a = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
b = 0

for x in a:
    while b <= 10:

    print(a, x, b)
    b += 1
```

My current program output is

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 0
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 3
```

so on

the output I would like

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 0
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] B 1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] C 2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] D 3
```

and so on
Although, when I try a different program it works perfectly?

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]

for a in list:
    print(a)
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: your `for/while` loop is not correctly indented. so it is hard to see what's wrong there.

Comment: I doubt your program outputs what you gave as "current program output". Even after fixing the indentation.

Comment: @wap26 please expand?

Comment: @Aymen first your code does not run as is (IndentationError) ; and if I indent either the `print` or the `print` and the `b +=…` in both cases the output is not what you mentioned.

Comment: @wap26 Sorry that was a formatting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have the `while` loop inside the outer `for` loop (that iterates over the elements of the list. So the inner while loop only exists when b becomes greater than `10`, and till then the value of `x` is `A`.

For what you want I would suggest using [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Example -

```
>>> a = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>>
>>> b = 0
>>> import itertools
>>> acycle = itertools.cycle(a)
>>> for i in range(11):
...     print(a,next(acycle),i)
...
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 0
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] B 1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] C 2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] D 3
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] E 4
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 5
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] B 6
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] C 7
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] D 8
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] E 9
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] A 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a double loop here (`while` inside `for`) and you never reset the `b` to 0. To get the result you expected, you should use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(a):
    print(a, x, idx)
```